# Why typescript enums doesn't helps to infer union type

Tags: typescript, enums, union, type-inference

I got the following class, which is the simple pubsub implementation:

```
interface IAction<N, T> {
    name: N,
    data: T
}

export class Communicator<A extends IAction<any, any>> {

    public subscribe(
       subscriber: { name: A['name']; handler: (data: A['data']) => void; }
    ) {}

    public emit(name: A['name'], data: A['data']): void {
    }
}
```

and then I use it like so:

```
enum ActionName {
    name1 = 'name1',
    name2 = 'name2'
}

type ExampleActions
    = { name: ActionName.name1, data: string }
    | { name: ActionName.name2, data: number };

const communicator = new Communicator<ExampleActions>();

let a = '';

communicator.subscribe({
    name: ActionName.name1,
    /* Expected no error, but get 
       TS2345: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.*/
    handler: data => a = data
});

/* Expected error Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number',
    but got no error*/
communicator.emit(ActionName.name2, 'string');
```

Looks like typescript may infer a type of concrete Action through concrete enum, but not. Is it a bug, or maybe I should do something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `A` is a union type so `A['data']` will be `string | number`  (all the possibilities in the union). Also there is no inference going on to determine that based on the type of `A['name']` the type of `data` should different, there is no relation between the two other that they are all the possible types for a field on the union.

You can get the desired outcome if you use conditional types in typescript 2.8 (unreleased at the time of writing, but you get it on `npm install -g typescript@next`, and it will be released in March)

```
// Helper type TActions will be a union of any number of actions 
// TName will be the name of the action we are intresed in 
// We use filter, to filter out of TActions  all actions that are not named TName 
type ActionData<TActions extends IAction<string, any>, TName> = 
           Filter<TActions, IAction<TName, any>>['data']; 

export class Communicator<A extends IAction<any, any>> {

    public subscribe<K extends A['name']>(
    subscriber: { name: K; handler: (data: ActionData<A, K>) => void; }
    ) {}

    public emit<K extends A['name']>(name: K, data: ActionData<A,K>): void {
    }
}
const communicator = new Communicator<ExampleActions>();

let a = '';

communicator.subscribe({ name: ActionName.name1, handler: d=> a = d}); // ok 
communicator.subscribe({ name: ActionName.name2, handler: d=> a = d}); // erorr as it should be

communicator.emit(ActionName.name1, a); // ok 
communicator.emit(ActionName.name2, a); // erorr as it should be
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `a` can be just a string, it never should be a number like `data` can be.

You can write next code:

```
handler: data => a = data as string
```

or

```
handler: data => a = <string>data
```